# C# Winforms: Is there any way to improve this simple custom Textbox code?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have been working on Custom TextBox control, which only allows alphanumeric characters. Note that I have not restricted characters from KeyPress, KeyUp event as I don't want to restrict copy/paste or any other operation that should be allowed generally. I have only trimmed non-alphanumeric character on paste operation. However, I am not sure whether the code I wrote is good or bad as I have very little experience of desktop application.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SaintThomas.UserControls
{
    class TextBoxForUserName : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);

            this.SuspendLayout();
            int startPos = this.SelectionStart;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(this.Text, "[^0-9_A-Z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                int reduceStartPos = this.Text.Length;
                this.Text = Regex.Replace(this.Text, "[^0-9_A-Z]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                startPos = (startPos <= 0) ? 0 : startPos - (reduceStartPos - this.Text.Length);
                if (this.Text.Length < startPos)
                {
                    startPos = this.Text.Length;
                }
                this.SelectionStart = startPos;
            }
            this.ResumeLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hey, Code Review is an excellent idea. Can I directly switch this post to Code Review or I have to re-post it?

Answer (score 4):

The best way of doing this is to use the [`MaskedTextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).

No reason to re-invent the wheel when you don't have to do so.

Comment: Does MaskedTextBox allow an arbitrary number of characters, or only a fixed mask? I thought it was the latter, which is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I totally agree but is it possible to allow variable length alphanumeric characters without PromptChar property in MaskedTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, the first `if` condition seems totally unnecessary because if you leave it out, the code does the same.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I just kept it because I don't want to set SelectionStart property in case of correct input. Once I will complete testing and confident that it won't affect current position, I will remove it.